Transformerless supply spiking
Added RM:
WARNING

Treat ALL parts of this circuit as ALWAYS at mains potential.
C1 MUST be 400v or greater and X OR Y RATED.


I have built this supply:

The only changes are

The resistor R1 shown in parallel with capacitor C! is not present.

C1 = 0.22uF in 250V

Diode bridge is a dip pin diode bridge,

Zener is 15V 3W Zener;

C2 = 470uF x 35V;

R2 is a 10k NTC surge protection thermistor


The doubt I have here is that, well at first use a 0.033uF C1, and no trouble... while changing the capacitor looks like the NTC is spiking, connected to the mains as the cap. Measured with the tester is 14.2V at the output, and a sort of 14 mA when I connect a yellow LED.
I will appreciate if someone can take my into the direction of eliminating the spiking. It does that when I connect the supply and disconnect, the rest of the time seems to work good.

This is a potentially lethally dangerous circuit. Are you sure, that the capacitor is X rated and can be used with 300 VAC? Sometimes there is only maximum DC voltage specified, which would better be 630 VDC in this case. What kind of NTC is used here? Can it withstand the peak AC voltage plus safety margin?

What do you mean "spiking"? Do you have any waveforms to describe this?

Regarding ratings, see: https://www.vishay.com/docs/28153/acfilmconnectionmains.pdf

Just to make sure. The "Ground" symbol is a bit misleading. PE must not be connected to the output negative, or you form a half wave short between L and PE.

Tell us more about C1, what kind, etc. Maybe even give part no. Not all caps are the same.

You don't "need" to replace the R2 resistor with an NTC (10 kOhm ?). Don't make R2 too high (50 Ohm-2 W, if you need it, is enough), because it should "need" more power ...

R2=10K NTC is FAR too high. || WARNING Treat ALL parts of this circuit as ALWAYS at mains potential. ||"This machine kills" - iof not you then maybe somebody else. Anything plugged into the out put MUST be treated as being at mains potential ALWAYS when the circuit is plugged into AC mains - even when the mains is turned off as switches break one pole only and your circuit MAY end up live but not operating. || I have seen mains connections that are bizarre but work. Some can easilyt kill. This circuit will help them to.

CLOSE VOTERS Safety issues are NOT an adequate reason for closure. Better such questions are well flagged re their dangers that that people go off to ask elsewhere and have people die.

@RussellMcMahon AFAIK this wasn't closed due to any safety issues, but because of missing details. This post is more or less a schematic and listing of some changes. But the actual fault description could (and IMO should) be more detailed. If you have a better understanding what OP meant with "while changing the capacitor looks like the NTC is spiking, connected to the mains as the cap. Measured with the tester is 14.2V at the output, and a sort of 14 mA when I connect a yellow LED.", if would be appreciated if you could rephrase these lines.

@TimWilliams  I added your Vishay link to my answer.

@DMaisterra - People have closed your questionbecause it is not clear. Could you please explain in more detail: " ...  If you have a better understanding what OP meant with "while changing the capacitor looks like the NTC is spiking, connected to the mains as the cap. Measured with the tester is 14.2V at the output, and a sort of 14 mA when I connect a yellow LED."

@Velvet I've asked the OP to do so. I read it as ~~~= "It worked OK when the cap was small but with the big cap I get output spikes". --> The NTC resistance seems FAR too high resistance. It may be going through heating and cooling cycles each cycle causing unexpected action. My answer suggests it is too high. || I understand the comment re clarity, noting also that I'd rather have an unclear but generally clear question here that somewhere else where people are less discerning. Others may disagree :-) .

R2=10K NTC is FAR too high.
The NTC heating/cooling action under load MAY account for the spiking action.
WARNING
Treat ALL parts of this circuit as ALWAYS at mains potential.
"This machine kills" - if not you then maybe somebody else.
Anything plugged into the out put MUST be treated as being at mains potential ALWAYS when the circuit is plugged into AC mains - even when the mains is turned off as switches disconnect one pole only, and your circuit MAY end up live but not operating.
I have seen mains connections that are bizarre but work.
Some can easily kill.
This circuit will help them to.

Capacitor C1 MUST X OR Y RATED for at least 250 VAC.
These are specially rated capacitors intended for use in mains supply situations.
"Just using" eg a non X or Y rated 400 VDC or greater capacitor may result in some or all of fireworks, fire, injury or death.
Really.
See:
Safety Capacitors First: Class-X and Class-Y Capacitors
Vishay 28153, 2022 AC Film Capacitors in Connection
With the Mains {≤ 60 Hz}
(Link supplied by Tim Williams)
AC voltage ratings for capacitors
